# Japanese Strings are not displayed when device region and language are set to Japan

Tags: ios, localization, ios9

Problem: Japanese Strings are not displayed when device region and language are set to Japan.

I've described my project environment below

Environment:
•   Device settings:
   - iPhone language is set to Japanese and region is set to Japan
   Xcode settings:
   - Select the project in the project navigator, Targets and open the info and
set to Japan in Localization native development region
•   iOS version: 9.0 or up

Expectation: App name and LocalizedStrings should be displayed as Japanese language
Actual result: App name is displayed by English and Strings are key values of NSLocalizedString.

In Info.plist file, if I change value from ja_JP to ja in CFBundleDevelopmentRegion, then I get Japanese string. I want to know why ja_JP is not working on iOS 9 or up? 
Below iOS 9, ja_JP is worked fine and I get Japanese strings and Japanese app name also.